# multiple path params vs. query params in a RESTful API for POST?

Tags: rest, api-design, restful-url

I am trying to implement a restful API

I have an entity called Programme ( description and location details)

I have entity called Timing ( Programme + start time + end time)

I have entity called Check-In ( Timing + User Details )

Scenario:
I need Check-In for Timings available,

How should be the ideal URL for the POST request,
Option A

```
POST /programme/:id/timing/:id/check-in
query param: null
```

Option B

```
POST /check-in
request body: {programme=id,timing:id}
```

the first approach will exactly use the id in the path param and directly identifies the resource
In the second approach, the consumer tells the type of resource, in the filter conditions mentions
the type of resource.

Note: we are using UUID for Programme and Timing resource which will make the URL slightly large

Comment: There is no such thing as a RESTful URL and there is a [request](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/376362/we-should-put-restful-url-to-rest) to remove this tag all along. A URL remains a URL no matter what. It is, as a whole, a pointer to a certain resource that provides some arbitrary data. One should not conclude some semantics from the characters in a URL as this leads to [typed resources](http://soabits.blogspot.com/2012/04/restful-resources-are-not-typed.html). In addition to that, REST has not much to do with [tag:api-design] also.

Comment: This is purely an opinion question.

Comment: @RomanVottner as you said there might be no standards, I wanted to know what is the best way/ various way to orchestrate the requirement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are going the Restful way, then you want to identify proper resources and have CRUD operations on those resources.

There are 3 resources:
- Programme
- User
- Schedule(Timing is a bad resource name for this)->belongs to-> Programme
- Register->belongs to(User, Schedule)

so to register, my restful endpoint will look like

POST /register
BODY {user_id: user1, schedule_id : s1}

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the right approach, I have renamed the resources as Sessions instead of timing. I will go with this approach " POST /register BODY {user_id: user1, schedule_id: s1} " except user id will be part of the header itself.

Answer (score 2):

Both will work but GET is more appropriate for requesting information. As long as your urls are under 4000 bytes, it's not going to be an issue.

Comment: Thanks for the response, My current use case is to register people for the individuals timing resource.
Currently, my model has check-in part of the Programme resource. Sorry if my question was not clear, updated the question now. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

[Caching](https://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Efielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm#sec_5_1_4) of resource representations is an important consideration in the REST architectural style.

The way that this is expressed in HTTP is that compliant caches are expected to [invalidate](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7234#section-4.4) the cached representation of a resource if we receive a non-error response to an unsafe request (like POST).  The URI is the cache key, and therefore the target-uri of the `POST` request identifies which cache entry is going to be evicted.

Therefore, in designing our protocol, we think about which *resources* are going to be changed by an action, and use the identifier of the resource to be changed as the target when we make the change.

What resource do we `GET` to see the effect of the change?  That should be the target of the change request.

```
POST /check-in
request body: {programme=id,timing:id}
```

This spelling would make sense if `GET /check-in` was the thing you would want to look at on the client.  From your description, that doesn't seem quite right -- it sounds too coarsely grained.

```
POST /programme/:id/timing/:id/check-in
query param: null
```

This, on the other hand, looks like it might be too finely grained; as though somebody thought that the right application of the single responsibility principle was that each `POST` handler would do exactly one thing.

Is there a `check-out` that "goes with" the `check-in`?  If so, those requests probably go to the same place

```
POST /programme/:id/timing/:id

action=check-in

POST /programme/:id/timing/:id

action=check-out
```

It might be that `programme`, rather than `timing`, is the correct grain for your domain

```
POST /programme/:id

action=check-in&timing=:id
```

Comment: thanks for the inputs, I have designed the resource in a different manner, My new design will look be on the similar lines of  "POST /register BODY {user_id: user1, timing: t1}", suggested by Karthik.